# Unable to create a constant value of type IdentityUserClaim

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I know you must say this post is duplicated, but I've already gone to multiple posts and the answers don't work on my code.

This is an Asp net web api server. Take a look:

```
    // GET: api/Vessels
    [HttpGet, Route(""), Route("{assets}")]
    public IQueryable<Vessel> GetVessels(string assets = "all")
    {
        var user = GetUser();

        if (IsAdmin(user))
        {
            return assets == "all"
                ? GetChildren(db.Vessels)
                : db.Vessels;
        }

        var claims = user.Claims
            .Where(c => c.ClaimType == "vessel")
            .ToList();

        var vessels = db.Vessels
            .Where(v => claims.Any(c => v.Id == int.Parse(c.ClaimValue)))
            .toList(); // will evaluate the query and get error

        return assets == "all"
            ? GetChildren(vessels)
            : vessels;
    }
```

and this is the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

On my tests I realised that the error is in this block:

```
claims.Any(c => v.Id == int.Parse(c.ClaimValue))
```

If I change it to 5 or anything else, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to go from string to int, but there is a way to go from int to string..

I believe this should work:

```
var vessels = db.Vessels
    .Where(v => claims.Any(c => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)v.Id) == c.ClaimValue))
    .ToList();
```

The original error is that Linq2EF passes the int.Parse which in turn tries to go to the DB and cannot form valid SQL for the join so it errors. The int.Parse on the Select can be processed by EF when it evaluates the results so your work-around will work but loads that whole set of IDs for "vessel" claims into memory on the .ToList(). It's not likely going to be a problem unless you're dealing with very large data sets or large # of requests.

Ideally though, your FK types should match the PKs they would be joined on to avoid issues like this, but with existing databases you often have to take what you're given. :)

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, now I understand. By now I'm using my work-around because the "whole set of IDs for vessel" is not more than 10 values, so this will not be a problem. But, I'll test your answer and I'll give you my feedback. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a work around and it works:

```
var claims = user.Claims
            .Where(c => c.ClaimType == "vessel")
            .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ClaimValue))
            .ToList();

var vessels = db.Vessels.Where(v => claims.Any(c => v.Id == c));
```

The code doesn't make any sense to me, can someone answer what happened?